# Multi Threading for PuLP library in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, pulp

I want to solve an optimisation problem using PuLP library in python. My optimisation problem has >10000 variables and lot of constraints. It takes very long time for PuLP to solve such big problems. Is there any way we can implement multi threading and gain speed ?

Any other solution/library for such big optimisation problems?

Answer (score 1):

Linear programming has not been very amenable to paralelisation, so your best bet to make the problem faster is either to use a different solver or to reformulate your problem.

You can get a feel for the speed at which other solvers can solve your problem by generating an MPS file (using the `writeMPS()` method on your propblem variable) and submitting it to [NeOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/).